# Globalization dxdatebox devextreme

Tags: javascript, html, devextreme

I am using devextreme 16.2
i have a dxdatebox in some form and it is in english language.
i want to change language to german and i have tried this:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/cultures/globalize.culture.de-de.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/globalize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/localization/dx.phonejs.de.js"></script>
    <script>
        Globalize.culture("de-DE");
    </script>
<script>
 $('#dateContainer').dxDateBox({
            value: new Date()
        });
</script>
</html>
```

but i the dxdatebox is still in english format.
and i have read this article but its not working yet.https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T135674.
how can i change language of datebox to german ?

Comment: Did you try to run the example online https://www.screencast.com/t/Uqe2AZyb0 ? It works as expected for me.

Comment: @Sergey yes it is work for me but in this article it has a folder name supplemental that have likelySubtags and other json file... but i dont have them. how can i got the?

Comment: Refer these [repos](https://github.com/unicode-cldr). This [article](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/Common/UI_Widgets/Localization_-_Use_Globalize/#Link_Dictionaries) may help, as well.

Comment: i do like in article and found the core supplemental json files . but still i can not show any dxdatebox. where i am doing wrong? @Sergey

Comment: It's too hard to understand what you are doing wrong. There aren't enough details in your question. Are there any errors in a browser console?

Comment: i have no error in console browser but have one warning : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check xhr.spec.whatwg.org. @Sergey

Comment: Look at this [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/023p2qrchan6o9v/T135674_JS.zip?dl=0). Be sure you are using a local web-server(apache, iis, etc.)

Comment: yes. its work . but from [here] (https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-cal-persian-full/tree/master/main/fa) i am using persian calender . i from [here](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-full/tree/master/main) i attach numbers and curriencies but when i click in calender i hav this error :E_UNSUPPORTED: Unsupported {"feature":"Julian day pattern `g`"}. @Sergey